# Kotlin, JPA and boolean fields

Tags: jpa, kotlin

I'm starting to introduce kotlin in our project and I'm converting some entities to kotlin as part as a bigger refactor.

My entity had a boolean active property:

```
private boolean active = true;

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(final boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}
```

Now in kotlin this should be:

```
var isActive: Boolean = true
```

The problem is that this way I have to refactor existing queries, not a big deal, but I was expecting a smoother transition.

I can do something like:

```
var active: Boolean = true

val isActive: Boolean
    get()= active
```

But it doesn't feel right. What would be the best way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can rename the getter like so

```
@get:JvmName("isActive")
var active: Boolean = true
```